# Vyos Default route

Tags: routing, vyos

I have set a default route on vyos using the command:

```
set protocols static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 10.121.191.254 distance '1'
```

But, the route appears to be inactive. The interface through which it should be reaching is eth0 and it is u/u. How do I "activate" this route?

[image: Interfaces]

[image: Routing Table]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, post the output as preformatted text using `{` and `}` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You configured a next-hop which isn't directly connected. A next-hop needs to be directly connected to be valid, so you should set the next-hop to a router which can be reached directly, at this moment your router does not know how to reach `10.121.191.254`.